# Ionic 5 ion-content ion-list scroll disabled after scroll down

Tags: ionic-framework, scroll, ion-list, ion-content

I am experiencing the following when having an ion-list within an ion-content:

At first I thought that the ion-refresh was causing this bug, but now that I removed it, it is still there.

So I have an ion-content and in there an ion-list. If I now go to the top of the page and i scroll the content a bit down, i can no longer scroll the ion-list, it even seemed to be cut off.

This happens on iOS - anybody any idea?

Theres not really code to show or any styles, as there are none.

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>

    </ion-list>
</ion-content
```

Comment: hi you can try this solution might be i will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572893/list-inside-ion-content-isnt-scrolling-vertically?rq=1

Comment: tried it, still the same effect. initially the scrolling works, until i drag the content down (like doing a refresh) - its cut off on the bottom.

Comment: hi is this possible to post your code snippet as well so i can check and let you answer of it thanks

Comment: there is not really much code to share, but i tried the ion-content solution now again and it seems that that, in combination with the ion-refresh did the trick. Anyway, such bugs are really annoying